# PyQT5 - QThreadPool - get number of queued threads

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

I try to get the number of queued jobs of QThreadPool for PyQT5.

my use case here:

```py
strWorkersStats = str(QThreadPool.globalInstance().activeThreadCount()) + \
          ' / todo..  need numQueuedThreads here..' + \
          '[' + str(QThreadPool.globalInstance().maxThreadCount()) + ']'
```

I'm wondering because this should be obvious need, but I couldn't find an answer..

Comment: activeThreadCount returns the number of active thread of the QThreadPool, why do you think it is not correct?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I need the number of *queued* threads ... eg .. 100 jobs assigned .. 3 active running .. 97 in the queue .. i need that number 97.

Comment: it seems that you can not know since that task is implemented by a class that belongs to Qt's private api: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/thread/qthreadpool.cpp?h=dev#n229

Comment: what is the way to go here?
should i create a custom MyThreadPool (inherited from QT5's ThreadPool) here? Or should I post a BugReport / FeatureRequest to QT project?

Comment: Inherit from QThreadPool will not help you since the inheritance would only be from the public API, from python it is impossible to access the private api. On the other the report may be a way but I think that if you accept your request it will take a long time to publish that data, make the report you do not lose anything in it. On the other hand, I'm thinking about how to do my own tracking, but I'm still analyzing how QThreadPool works internally. Another option is to find a class that does the same in python. Do you know if any kind of python does the same QThreadPool task?

Comment: Thank you for your support! Writing my own ThreadQueue was my initial idea before i spotted QT5's ThreadPool. I will implement my own. But I would like to write a feature request to QT anyway. Do you know where i can do that?

Comment: see this: https://wiki.qt.io/Reporting_Bugs